# Dietary Requirements after booking but before flight

Tags: food-and-drink, dietary-restrictions, in-flight-services

I have booked transatlantic flights with Aer Lingus and I have yet to be contacted about any dietary requirements pre flight (flight is less than one week away)

I can pre-book meals on their website with my booking ref and name (no mention of vegetarian or vegan options though) for both legs of the journey (for an added cost) but I cannot find anywhere to tell the carrier about dietary requirements before flight.

Do Aer lingus offer this service or is it a free for all?

I have always arranged this pre flight with a carrier before using an online tool or when making the booking, and I can swear that I have done this with Aer Lingus too in the past.

Comment: Have you asked Air Lingus to contact you, or are you expecting the airline to call all passengers before their flight to ask for dietary restrictions?

Comment: I would expect and email and/or the functionality to do it on their website.

Comment: I would presume so @JoErNanO its transatlantic (long-haul)

Comment: The first page I could find with Google explains the different special meals offered by Air Lingus (among them both vegetarian and vegan options) and tells you to contact them at least 24 hours before the flight to order. Wouldn't that answer your question? https://www.aerlingus.com/travel-information/special-assistance/dietary-needs/

Comment: Nobody's going to proactively call you to offer you a special meal. That's not how airlines work. I would call them with your request.

Comment: On planes they serve minuscule meals, so it's best not to bother and bring your own food with you.

Comment: https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/us/flying-withus/dining/book-the-cook/

Comment: @ZachLipton KLM, Air France and BA have all emailed me in advance to notify them via their website of any dietary requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, I don't think so.

By the website wording, I inferred that they want *you* to contact *them*. On their website it says (direct quote):

> If you have a special dietary requirement for medical or religious reasons, or you may be travelling with small children, we can provide a suitable alternative meal if this is requested sufficiently in time - **at least 24 hours in advance of your flight departure**

**Or 48 hours if you are business class.**

So you need to [contact them](https://www.aerlingus.com/support/contact-us/) with one of these meal codes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for copying 1:1 from the web site I linked to in my comment.

Comment: @Aganju Are you talking to me?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Oh, didn't notice your comment! :) Ah well, no plagiarism intended